# Add text to an inactive viewcontroller's textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a list view of all the entities from my Core Data.

When tapped on, it should be pushing the values of the entity selected into the text fields in the view that is about to get pushed onto the navigation stack, but it doesn't.

What confuses and irritates me, is that if I use `NSLog`, it logs, but I use the same code and it doesn't output that same information into the `textFields`. the title also changes as it should, and it baffles me as to why the textfields dont. Am I missing something? Am I accessing the Athlete entity incorrectly?

Here is my code snippets (note `Athlete.h` is the dynamically create core data attributes, `AllAthletes.h` is the `table view` and `AthleteDetail.h` is the detail view getting pushed)

```
allathletes.h

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    Athlete *athlete = (Athlete *)[athleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    AthleteDetail *athleteDetail= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showAthlete"];
    athleteDetail.firstDetailTextField.text = athlete.first;
    athleteDetail.title = athlete.full;
    NSLog(@"Full Name: %@",athlete.full);
    NSLog(@"Parent's Full Name: %@", athlete.pfull);
    NSLog(@"Number: %@",athlete.phone);
    NSString *firstNameText = athleteDetail.firstDetailTextField.text;
    firstNameText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",athlete.first];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:athleteDetail animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Does firstDetailTextField has an Outlet?

Comment: it has an outlet and is properly connected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object for AthleteDetail `AthleteDetail *athleteDetail= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showAthlete"];` it does not initialise the controls subviewed.

The best way to get the desired the behaviour is to create a property named "athleteName" in AthleteDetail class

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * athleteName
```

now instead of `athleteDetail.firstDetailTextField.text = athlete.first;`
write the following code

```
athleteDetail.athleteName = athlete.first;
```

now in viewDidLoad of AthleteDetail class, assign athleteName to your textfield

```
firstDetailTextField.text = _athleteName;
```

I hope this works for you.. :)

Comment: there is a tiny delay though, like 0.3 seconds. is there any way to make it less?

Comment: delay while showing the text or delay in navigating to the AthleteDetail? make sure you have set the text in viewDidLoad method

Comment: I got it, I just set the "firstDetailTextField.text = _athleteName;" in viewWillAppear, so it loads before the user sees and then its there with no instant appearance. thanks!